# webRTC timestamp information

Tags: javascript, timestamp, webrtc, rtp

I am working on a school project that uses webRTC. Webrtc uses rtp to payload data when sending video or audio. In the RTP specifications, it seems clear that a timestamp is used to reorder received packet when playing it.
Is there any way to access to this timestamp information? Isn't it the subject of this [API](http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time)?
Our aim would be for the receiver of a media stream to tell the delay between him playing the stream and the time it was sent.

If you can help me or tell me where to find the information, it would be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

A short(!) glance over the Firefox code gave no indication for the RTP packet-timestamp to be able to get read by JavaScript.

You *do* have the two [high resolution](http://w3c.github.io/hr-time/) timestamps in the [statistics](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#statistics-model) ([example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800010/can-someone-comprehensively-explain-the-webrtc-stats-api) to get the stats). I doubt that it is useful for your goal besides some rough to very rough estimations but if that is sufficiently exact for you...