# Measuring bandwidth usage between several local WebRTC instances

Tags: webrtc, bandwidth

I have a prototype WebRTC application and I want to measure the bandwidth usage for a given peer at different scenarios. For example, measuring the up/down bandwidth usage when connected to 4, 8, 12 other peers.

I only have a few machines available, so my first thought was to just launch multiple instances per machine. But how do I measure the bandwidth usage correctly? I tried using Wireshark and NetLimiter, but I started getting weird results.

The problem was that I only measured bandwidth usage between the machines and not between the actual peers themselves.

For example, if I have 2 machines with 4 peers each, I want to measure a given peers bandwidth usage with the other 7 peers, even though 3 of the peers are actually on the same machine. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Use [stats](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29800010/918910).

Comment: Yea, I just realised that myself, thanks! :)